# Aggregate not giving any results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm attempting to do partial search in my mongoose database for city names.
This is how I have Trips defined.

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const TravelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        creator: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User' 
        },

        numPeople: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },

        startDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },

        endDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },

        destination: [{
            city: {type: String, required :true},
            state: {type: String, required:true }
        }],
        
        budget :[{
            travelCost: {type: Number},
            foodCost: {type: Number},
            lodgingCost: {type: Number},
            miscellaneousCost: {type: Number}
        }]

    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Trips', TravelSchema);
```

No matter what I try, aggregate is not giving me any results (not even an error) and I have no idea why.
This is what my search looks like. Ideally the Trip.aggregate I have commented out would work but even the simple one is not giving any output

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Trip = require('../models/Trips');

/*Trip.aggregate([
            //{ $project : {'destination' : 1}},
            { $unwind : "$destination"},
            /*{
                $match: {
                    'destination.city' :{
                        "$regex" : new RegExp(req.body.city), "$options" : "i"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]),function(err,results){
                console.log(err);
                console.log(results);   
                console.log("Im in here2");

            }*/

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Im in here");

    Trip.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                numPeople: {
                    $gt: 0,
                    $lt: 10
                }
            }
        }]),
        function(err, results) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log(results);
        }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I know I have things in the database with those fields and I should get a result for the age.
Here is some of the data in my mongodb.
[MongoSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICFwK.png)

Comment: you are doing a matching of `destination.city` but you are passing `req.body.state`. Should that be `req.body.city`

Comment: @Vishnu oh yeah thanks. Ill fix that.